# Passing React Props with CSS and using them in a component with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a prop in React, I am trying to use with CSS style settings. You eventually will be able to change the direction.  I have created a prop with CSS and an object.  Heres the code for it.

```
export const styling = (props: any) => {
    let styles = {
           box: {
            transform: 'rotate(90deg)'
           }
          box2: { 
            transform: 'rotate(95deg)'
           }
        }
    }
```

How do I call this in the components the correct way?  I want to call it like this:

```
<Dropdownstyling styles={box}}/>
```

But that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the style object you created:

```
<Dropdownstyling style={styling.styles.box}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just passing `box` to the styles object , you need to pass `styling`

`<Dropdownstyling style={styling.styles.box}/>`